# Що таке «чайма» і звідки це слово пішло

Tags: значення-слів

Натрапив у словнику e2u.org.ua на [таке](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on):

> Українсько-англійський словник 1955 (К.Андрусишин, Я.Крет)
>   **ча́йма (-ми)** *f* rigging; sails;
>         **ча́ймовий (-ва, -ве)** of sails:
>         **ча́ймове судно́**, sail boat.

Намагався знайти значення, але пошук в інтернеті не допоміг. Що це слово означає, звідки воно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значення слова чайма [знаходимо](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0) в словнику Грінченка:

> **Чайма, ми**, *ж*. Парусъ. Встрѣчено лишь въ фальсифицированной думѣ о
>   походѣ князя язычника. *Стали корабелі свої чайми підимать, як стадо
>   лебедів вони од берега одпливали*. ЗОЮР. І. 176.

Отже чайма — це рідкісне слово, яке означає **вітрило**.

У шостому томі ЕСУМ зазначається таке:

> Чайма — щогла з вітрилами; вітрило. Походження неясне.

Merriam-Webster дає [такі значення](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Chaima):

> карибський народ на узбережжі Венесуели; представник цього народу; мова цього народу.

Я подумав, що, можливо, Джозеф Конрад, який бував на тих узбережжях, має це слово десь у своїх творах, але поки не знаходжу. Але однаково могло прибути з тих країв.

Арабською [Чайма](https://www.behindthename.com/bb/fact/4736196) і Шайма — "with a beauty spot" або [мушка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0)), але зв'язок знайти поки складно.

/продовжую шукати походження.

Comment: ось звідки взявся *rigging* - це про такелаж

Comment: @Yola так, зі значенням зрозуміло, тепер лишається знайти походження. Доведеться попітніти. Дідько, важко.